# VBA for Macbook - macro not saving output file

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm working on macro for MacBook for separating codes that we paste in file.

After running codes should show up in a folder on my desktop called Tour Codes.

However, file is not getting saved and macro shows error.

I've tried multiple adjustments and changing location of file but the problem remains.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
Sub create_files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iName, iPath
iName = GetUserNameMac
'Get Path and Workbook Name
'iPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
iPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:" & iName & ":Desktop:Tour Codes"
Sheets("Data").Select

...
'create files
Dim r1, ddate, gate, id, cap, firstrow, rowcount, newcode
r1 = 2
firstrow = 2
...

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'save file
    ChDir "Macintosh HD:Users:" & iName & ":Desktop:Tour Codes"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    iPath & ":" & id & "_" & Format(ddate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "_" & gate & "_" & firstrow & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs iPath & ":" & merchWk
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs iPath & "/" & merchWk
    Windows("Gate 1 codes macro.xlsm").Activate

    'copy rows to file
    'Rows(firstrow & ":" & firstrow + rowcount - 2).Select
    Range(Cells(firstrow, 1), Cells(firstrow + rowcount - 2, 1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(id & "_" & Format(ddate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "_" & gate & "_" & firstrow & ".csv").Activate
    'Cells(2, 1).Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'save file
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Windows("Gate 1 codes macro.xlsm").Activate
    firstrow = r1 - 1
    r1 = firstrow

Loop Until r1 > lastrow
End Sub
Function GetUserNameMac() As String
Dim sMyScript As String
sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"   
GetUserNameMac = MacScript(sMyScript)

End Function
```

VBA errors out on these lines:

[image: error]

Comment: Check the output of `Debug.Print iPath & ":" & id & "_" & Format(ddate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "_" & gate & "_" & firstrow & ".csv"` and tell us what it is.

Comment: I run the code, now it errors out here: https://imgur.com/5pzollo

Comment: Ok the `Debug.Print` line prints something in the Immediate Window (you can open it via the menu). See [Use the Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-immediate-window). What was printed there?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6g0PoXd  is this one ok?

Comment: Ok does this complete path exist for sure? And what was the error message of your `SaveAs` line?